# Missing/misplaced particles after reopening the .blend file

Tags: particles

I got the grass essentials pack, everything works as it should but after closing and reopening the .blend file certaian grass types are behaving very strange (they are basically just dots without any object and floating like crazy). I have to append the grass group again to make it work properly. It's fine after that procedure but it's also very annoying to do it every time I save and exit -> open my project again.

[image][image]

Comment: Will it solve if you go to the first frame with shift+left arrow?

Comment: First frame is the same problem. However after frame 99 it disappears entirely so maybe it has something to do with the timeline. Although I have no idea what.